# Parsing text file to get a selection of text

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have a text file where I want to grab a section of text so I can put that into two arrays one being ingredients the other is directions.

for the ingredients, I can do something like below but I can't guarantee the integrity of it.

```
ingredients = []
list.each_line do |l|
  ingredients << l if l =~ /\d\s?\w.*/
end
```

this is the text blob :

```
635860
581543
2011-03-21T13:50:10Z

Image:black bean soup.jpg|right|Mexican Black Bean Soup

== Ingredients ==
1lb black beans
2 tbsp extra-virgin olive oil
2 onions, large, diced
6 cloves garlic, minced
1 cup tomato, peeled, seeded, and chopped (fresh or canned)
1 sprig epazote, fresh or dried (optional)
1 tbsp chipotle pepper|chipotle chiles, canned, chopped (or ¼ tsp cayenne)
1 tsp cumin, ground
1 tsp coriander seed|coriander, ground
2 tsp salt

== Directions ==
Soak the black beans for 2 hours and drain.
In a deep pot, heat the olive oil over medium heat.
Add the onions and cook about 5 minutes.
Until translucent.
Add the black beans|beans, garlic, and 6 cups cold water.
Bring to a boil, skimming any foam that rises to the surface.
Reduce to a simmer.
In an hour or when the black beans|beans are soft, add the tomato, epazote, chipotle chile peppers|chile, cumin, coriander, and salt.
Continue cooking until the black beans|beans start to break down and the broth begins to thicken.
Taste for seasoning and add salt and pepper if needed.
If you’re serving this soup immediately, you may want to thicken it by puréeing a cup or two of the black beans|beans in a blender or food processor and then recombining them with the rest of the soup.
The soup will thicken on its own if refrigerated overnight.

Category:Black bean Recipes
Category:Chile pepper Recipes
Category:Chipotle pepper Recipes
Category:Epazote Recipes
Category:Mexican Soups
Category:Tomato Recipes
bx0ztz9xbf8qr9z4gwkad26u6q3hly3
```

Comment: This is all find and good until someone has "Half a pound of butter" or "two whole eggs" in the recipe.

Comment: Couple of tips: Instead of using the Perl-style `=~` operator, use `.match(...)` instead which makes what's going on a lot more clear. Secondly, use `/\A\s*\d\s*\w.*/` as a way of anchoring it to the start of the line where they're could be a couple of spaces for no reason.

Comment: The way I usually approach problems like this is to get a corpus of data full of all sorts of ugly edge cases, then write a parser that handles them. The thing that'll save you here is *unit tests*, especially the sort where you can define the output in a standard form like JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do here, is instead of trying to match data that you likely have no control over, try to match that data that it looks like you might have some control over. Specifically, it looks to me like the lines `== Ingredients ==` and `== Directions ==` and `Category:Tomato Recipes` could possibly be part of the file format, not entered by the user. So, I'd just split the text up whenever you see a line that looks like that:

```
sections = list.each_line.slice_before do |line|
  line.match?(/\A(==|[a-zA-Z]+:)/)
end.entries
```

and then you can just `assoc` the data out of the groups:

```
puts sections.assoc("== Ingredients ==\n")
puts '---'
puts sections.assoc("== Directions ==\n")
```

This still has some flaws (if the user enters something like `Note: Preheat oven first` as part of the directions, this would end up splitting that, thinking it's metadata), but should be a large step forward, and can be tweaked from here.

Comment: Thank you that has helped me a lot.